# Access array in a switch

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I’m having trouble in acess and modify an array from class main inside a Switch in view.
The array is declared that’s way in main:

```
Client[] clients = new Client[i]
```

The program its about running a pub in which the object Client have: Name, What table is sit, and order.
And the switch to add client it’s like this:

```
 int clients[desiredTable] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the table that will register."));
```

And its supposed to add information about the client in array “clients”.
If someone could help I would be thankful.

Comment: `int clients[desiredTable] = ...` is not valid java code (AFAIK) You **maybe** need `clients[desiredTable] = ...`

Comment: Yes, something like `int desiredTable = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the table that will register.")); clients[desiredTable] = /*set the client on the given table*/` is needed instead.